# How do I count too see how many numbers and letters are in a user inputted string?

Tags: java, loops, user-input

I have been asked to write an application that prompts the user for a String that contains at least five letters and at least five digits. Continuously reprompt the user until a valid String is entered. Display a message indicating whether the user was successful or did not enter enough digits, letters, or both.

I am a beginner programmer and I need help figuring out how too make this application work correctly. My issue is I am unable to figure out how to make my program interpret the letters and numbers from user input. Here is what I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Declare variables. 
    String message;
    int numLetters = 0;
    int numDigits = 0;
    boolean letters = false;
    boolean digits = false;
    // Input.
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Type a message with 5 letters and 5 digits: ");
    message = input.nextLine();
    // Loop through string.
```

Comment: Convert the input to a `char` array, loop of the `char` array and use `Character.isLetter` and `Character.isDigit`.  See [`Character`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) and [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) for more details. [The for Statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) and [Arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) might also be of help

Answer (score 1):

The dark art of regular expressions can crush this problem with just one method call:

```
public static boolean check(String input) {
    return input.matches("(?i)(?=(.*?[a-z]){5})(?=(.*?\\d){5}).*");
}
```

Breakdown:

- the `matches()` method accepts a regex that must match the *whole* string to return true
- the basic matching regex is `.*`, which matches everything
- `(?i)` means "ignore case"
- `[a-z]` is a character class as means "any lowercase letter"
- `.*?[a-z]` means "0-n chars (but the smallest number possible) then a letter"
- `(.*?[a-z]){5}` means "5 copies of the above"
- `(?=(.*?[a-z]){5})` is a "look ahead", which asserts, but does not consume the input (so you can fire another one) and means "there must be at least 5 letters in the input"
- `(?=(.*?\\d){5})` is similar, but asserts there are at least 5 numbers

Answer (score 0):

Create a method to check if it has 5 letters and 5 digits:

```
public boolean check(String input){
    int numDigits = 0;
    int numLetters = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<input.length();i++){
        if(Character.isLetter(input.charAt(i))) numLetters++;
        if(Character.isDigit(input.charAt(i))) numDigits++;
    }
    return (numDigits >= 5) && (numLetters >= 5);
}
```

Then you can add this method to a while loop:

```
while(!check(message)){
    // get the input again and assign it to message
}
```

Answer (score -4):

HA!!!! I GOT IT... For all you kids out there that need an answer to REFERENCE, check this out! Since everyone likes to dance around giving a good answer here is copy and paste code that will work. (Please dont hand it in as your own, but check out how this PITA code works!

```
//Date: 5/31/2015
//Subject: Mod 4, pg 389, Question 3 
//Purpose:User is to input 5 digits and 5 letters. It will re prompt user until at least 5 digits and 5 letters are typed in.
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FiveLettersAndFiveDigits
{
public static void main(String[] args)
   {
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
int numDigits = 0;
int numLetters = 0;
String message;
System.out.println("Please enter a 5 letter word and 5 digits.");
message = keyboard.nextLine();
while(numLetters < 5 &&numDigits <5)
{
for(int i=0; i < message.length();i++)
    if(Character.isLetter(message.charAt(i)))  ++numDigits;
for(int j=0; j < message.length();j++)
    if(Character.isDigit(message.charAt(j))) ++numLetters;
    if(numLetters >= 5 && numDigits >= 5)
    {
    System.out.println("You have " +numDigits+ " numbers and " +numLetters+ " letters, great job.");
    }
    else
    {
    System.out.println("You have typed in "+numDigits+" letters and "+numLetters+" numbers. Please try again.");
    System.out.println("Please enter a 5 letter word and 5 digits.");
    message = keyboard.nextLine();
    continue;
    }
 }
 System.out.println("This problem was no fun, hahaha. Took me like 3 hours!");
}
}
```

And that is that folks! Thank your lucky stars you had a reference online that was straight forward! hahaha Nothing sucks more than looking for some kind of direction and all you get is half @$$3D hints. Feel free to check out how this works.